# Sql. Different row number. No PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Good day.
In my work I found a little problem. I think that I'm worse SQL-man. I can't solve two days.
I have a little sql table consist of informathion of students, classes and schools like
I need the serial number for each new (class and school) for each student in each class. Without PL/SQL

```
School       Class          Name
first        1b             Smith 
first        1b             Jones 
first        1b             Willams 
second       1a             Taylor 
second       1b             Brown 
second       1b             Davies
```

And Table I need

```
Number        School       Class  Name 
   1          first        1b     Smith
   2          first        1b     Jones
   3          first        1b     Willams
   1          second       1a     Taylor
   1          second       1b     Brown
   2          second       1b     Davies
```

Comment: Solved by SELECT row_number() over(partition BY  ORDER BY )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you solved it but I think anybody looking this up wants to see the full solution

SQL Fiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6756/8

```
SELECT 
   row_number() over (partition BY school, class ORDER BY school, class) as nr
   , s.*
from students s
```

Now the counting of rows only is by school and class.

Whenever I deal with analytical functions I have to scratch my head a bit and usually refer always to this page which I find an excellent tutorial and memory refresher: http://www.orafaq.com/node/55

Edit:

Following the remark from Clockwork-Muse I have removed the remark about what the `order by`within the analytical function does and quote the Oracle documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407

> **order_by_clause**
>
> Use the order_by_clause to specify how data is ordered within a
>   partition. For all analytic functions you can order the values in a
>   partition on multiple keys, each defined by a value_expr and each
>   qualified by an ordering sequence.

Comment: Technically, that `ORDER BY` won't produce stable results (that is, subsequent runs over the same data isn't guaranteed to produce the same numbering); this is due to it being your `PARTITION BY` criteria.  Granted, practically it's likely to be stable, given how RDBMSs tend to be implemented.  Still, it'd be better to use a column that provides a stable sort (such as `name`), although this'll probably give the fastest results.

Comment: Excellent hint. I made an edit. Thank you very much.